# Why attribute fields for features appear greyed?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, attribute-table

I added an excel in an attribute table using join opperation; I added the csv excel into geodatabase using import table opperation. The joined fields appear into attribute table, but when I right-click on a feature, and click on attribute, the attributes fields on the right side appear greyed.[image]
For an other layer, the attribute fields for feature appear blacked. 
 [image]
What can I do in order to make attribute fields for the first layer to appear blacked like in the second case?

Comment: I suppose the black attributes tell you they are editable as opposed to the non editable grey attributes.

Answer (score 1):

That is happening to you simply because the fields that are gray are in the joined table and are not in the layer you are editing (e.g. they are not editable).

The only way they are going to be editable is to make them a part of the layer you are editing so the steps you need to take are ...

1) Export the data with the joined table as a new layer.

2) Edit the new layer that now includes the fields from the joined table.

Comment: I can`t export the data because the joined fields are form a excel table not from another layer.

Comment: @SamLee If you export the data the joined fields will be added as fields in your new feature class (ie it will not be joined to Excel)

Comment: I exported it but I want to add this fields to a layer. Or, it doesn`t allow me to export data from a table to a layer. It shows only other excel files which I can export to. http://tinypic.com/r/30x7wg3/9

Comment: I solve it. I didn`t understand that I should export the data from the layer in which those fields was joined. I thought that I should export the data from the table. After I exported the data from the layer with all new joined fields,  into the new layer the attributes appear with black and I can copy-paste features with their attributes. Thanks, guys...I`m so happy.